# is it possible to have a set comprehension in haskell?

Tags: haskell, set, list-comprehension

In Haskell we have list generators, such as:

```
[x+y | x<-[1,2,3], y<-[1,2,3]]
```

with which we get

```
[2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6]
```

Is it possible to have a set generator which doesn't automatically add an element if it is already in the list?

In our example we would obtain:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

If so, how? If it is not already implemented, how would you implement it?

Comment: No, there's no such thing in Haskell, you need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haskell can do this, but not quite out-of-the-box.

The basic underpinning is that a list comprehension can also be written as a monadic binding chain, in the list monad:

```
Prelude> [x+y | x<-[1,2,3], y<-[1,2,3]]
[2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6]
Prelude> [1,2,3] >>= \x -> [1,2,3] >>= \y -> return (x+y)
[2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6]
```

...or, with better readable `do`-syntax (which is syntactic sugar for monadic binding)

```
Prelude> do x<-[1,2,3]; y<-[1,2,3]; return (x+y)
[2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6]
```

In fact, there's a language extension that also turns all list comprehensions into syntactic sugar for such a monadic chain. Example in the tuple (aka writer) monad:

```
Prelude> :set -XMonadComprehensions 
Prelude> [x+y | x <- ("Hello", 4), y <- ("World", 5)] :: (String, Int)
("HelloWorld",9)
```

So really, all we need is a *set monad*. This is sensible enough, however `Data.Set.Set` is *not* a monad on **Hask** (the category of all Haskell types) but only only the subcategory that satisfies the `Ord` constraint (which is needed for lookup / to avoid duplicates). In the case of sets, there is however a hack that allows hiding that constraint from the actual monad instance; it's used in the [`set-monad` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Monad.html). Et voilà:

```
Prelude Data.Set.Monad> [x+y | x<-fromList[1,2,3], y<-fromList[1,2,3]]
fromList [2,3,4,5,6]
```

The hack that's needed for `instance Monad Set` comes at a price. It works like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}
import qualified Data.Set as DS

data Set r where
  Prim :: (Ord r => DS.Set r) -> Set r
  Return :: a -> Set a
  Bind   :: Set a -> (a -> Set b) -> Set b
  ...
```

What this means is: a value of type `Data.Set.Monad.Set Int` does not really contain a concrete set of integers. Rather, it contains an *abstract syntax expression* for a computation that yields a set as the result. This isn't great for performance, in particular it means that values won't be shared. So don't use this for big sets.

There's a better option: use it directly as a monad *in the proper category* (which only contains orderable types to begin with). This unfortunately requires even more language-bending, but it's possible; I've made an example [in the `constrained-categories` library](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/blob/master/examples/Set.hs).

Comment: By chance you can explain what stops this monad instance from making its way to `base`?

Comment: @Kindaro just did that... (BTW, there's no set type in `base`, if anything it would go in `containers`).

Answer (score 5):

If your values can be put in `Data.Set.Set` (i.e. they are in class `Ord`) you can just apply `Data.Set.toList . Data.Set.fromList` to your list:

```
Prelude> import Data.Set
Prelude Data.Set> Data.Set.toList . Data.Set.fromList $ [x+y | x<-[1,2,3], y<-[1,2,3]]
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

The complexity of this would be `O(n log n)`.

If the type obeys `(Eq a, Hashable a)`, you can use `Data.HashSet` in much the same way. The average complexity is `O(n)`.

If all you have is `Eq`, you have to get by with something like `Data.List.nub`:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> nub [x+y | x<-[1,2,3], y<-[1,2,3]]
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

but the complexity is inherently quadratic.

Comment: This doesn't even require using any `Set` type, you can as well use `map head . group . sort` for removing the duplicates in _O_ (_n_ · log _n_). The problem is, if you have intermediate sets with lots of duplicates in a calculation, the size grows _exponentially_, so this is only ok if the sets are mostly disjoint anyway.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't quite get it, why would the size grow exponentially and in what case?

Comment: It's exponential in _n_ in the scenario where you have _n_ iterative computation steps, each outputting a set of size _k_ including _O_ (_k_) duplicates. In this case, if you calculate with intermediate lists instead, the second step will also give duplicates of each of the duplicates of the first step and so on.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I see. So one would have to remove duplicates in intermediate lists too. In your code `fromList` is doing this.

Comment: Well, more relevantly, the `>>=` of the set monad removes duplicates after each join.